# How do I monitor Microsoft Outlook to determine load time and factors involved using a third party program, PowerShell, or C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, outlook

I'm tasked with a project to find, or create, a third party application that will be used for automation to monitor how long it takes to open Microsoft Outlook and log all actions taken while opening, such as addons, .ost or .pst file sizes, open/shared shared mailboxes. I have searched online for third party applications or PowerShell programs that could do this. I have even searched for starter points on how to develop a PowerShell script or even start writing a program in C# that could do this. I am using Microsoft Outlook 2016. I'm currently at intermediate level with C# programming and up for learning more to accomplish this project. I have the following questions:

1. Does anyone know of a 3rd party or PowerShell script that will accomplish this goal?
2. Alternatively, how would I even begin a C# script to accomplish this?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Maybe have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/trace-processing/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after having a more seasoned programmer look at my script, he made some necessary changes and comments.

```
clear-host
$CSVFile = Read-Host "Enter CSV log file and path - (C:\temp\outlook.csv)"
$ProcMonTest = Read-Host "Enter app path - (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE)"
$ProcMon = "C:\tools\Procmon.exe" # this would be the path to wherever procmon.exe is
$ProcMonBack = "C:\Temp\ProcMonTest.pml"
$LaunchBAT = Read-Host "Enter path to the BAT file to launch the app to be tested - (c:\tools\StartOutlook.bat)" # use a bat file to get past PowerShell security
$CredsForApp = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Run App As?", "Enter creds in domain\username format to run testing app:", "", "") # this gives us the creds to run the app to be tested as 
 
# make sure backing file isn't present in case it wasn't deleted on last run
$FileExists = Test-Path $ProcMonBack
if ($FileExists -eq $true){
Remove-Item $ProcMonBack -force
}
 
& $ProcMon /Quiet /AcceptEula /Minimized /backingfile $ProcMonBack 
 
do{
Start-Sleep -seconds 90 # procmon.exe /waitforidle doesn't appear to work well when scripted with PowerShell
$ProcMonProcess = Get-Process | where {$_.Path -eq $ProcMon}
}while(
$ProcMonProcess.Id -eq $null
)
(Start-Process cmd -Credential $CredsForApp -Argument "/c $LaunchBAT")

Start-Sleep -seconds 90 # adjust this time based on how long the test run is needed
 
$ProcMonTestProcess = Get-Process | where {$_.Path -eq $ProcMonTest}
Stop-Process $ProcMonTestProcess.Id -Force
 
& $ProcMon /Terminate
 
Start-Sleep -seconds 60 # procmon.exe can take a long time to exit, this ensures it does before proceeding
 
# Read the procmon.exe backing file and export as CSV
& $ProcMon /openlog $ProcMonBack /SaveAs $CSVFile
& $ProcMon /Terminate

Start-Sleep -seconds 60 # procmon.exe can take a long time to exit, this ensures it does before proceeding

# Clean up procmon.exe backing file
$FileExists = Test-Path $ProcMonBack
if ($FileExists -eq $true){
Remove-Item $ProcMonBack -force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fully answer your question, but I might have some insights how to monitor the startup speed of outlook. Using powershell or C# you could start Outlook and measure the time it took to start it up fully. Maybe more information can be gathered using the Outlook COM Interface but this way you can atleast see the timings.

Simple test script (Powershell) to show boot speed:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"

$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$folder = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$explorer = $folder.GetExplorer()
$explorer.Display()

$sw.Stop()
$sw.Elapsed
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look at this.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get this to open with a user's domain credentials or against a signed in user? I remember finding this script when I was searching for this answer and that was the problem I had then and still have. It launches Outlook for a new user setup. I need to check logged in users for problems loading Outlook after signing onto the domain.

Comment: It's a good question. Would be very nice to know which user is experiencing Outlook (office in general) issues before they call support. I will look into it and update my answer if I find anything usefull. Please let me know if you find a good answer by answering your own question

Comment: see my answer below.

Comment: the answer provided does well to launch Outlook and test the speed but it's not accurate if not launched as current user because the Add-ins and all the shared mail boxes aren't loaded. Maybe look at revising it with the answer I provided.